# Fastest way to calculate the mean of several numpy arrays in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

I have a list with 10.000 numpy arrays, each containing 217088 numbers. Now I want to calculate the average array

Minimalistic code example:

```
import numpy as np

l = []

l.append(np.array([1,2,3]))
l.append(np.array([10,11,12]))
l.append(np.array([5,6,7]))

np.average(l,axis=0)
```

Is there any faster way than np.average ?

Comment: Would all elements in that list be of length `3`? If so, you could use `np.mean` : `np.mean(l,axis=0)`.

Comment: yes they are all the same length (217088 in my case), thank you - is mean faster than average?

Comment: @Divakar `np.mean` takes more time, `np.average` is faster

Comment: @CarlesMitjans What's the size/shape of the dataset that you tested on?

Comment: @Divakar I used it with OP's example. Should it be faster with larger datasets?

Comment: @Divakar I tested it with a `1000 x 217088` dataset. Both `np.mean` and `np.average` took roughly the same time, although further analysis should be implemented.

Comment: Actually, `np.average` is a little bit faster

Comment: @Kev1n91 You can use `einsum` : `np.einsum('ij->j',l)/float(len(l))`, but watch out for precision issues with overflow, if you have lots of numbers to be summed up for.

Comment: Thank you, since the numbers are distances - and so I may have negative  / positives values - I am rather scared to use einsum